# Invalid timeout type specified: page load

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I'm new to Selenium and automation testing and I'm facing the following error message:

```
org.openqa.selenium.InvalidArgumentException: Invalid timeout type specified: page load
```

When running the test / login / user and pass are typed extremely slow - like 1 symbol per 10 - 15 sec. I'm able to log in, but test failed with the mentioned error message. 
How can I fix it so test runs bit faster, which I think is the problem?

Windows 10
IE 11
ie driver 32bit 3.5.0

and the code:

```
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {

    System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "D:\\Documents\\SeleniumDriver\\IEDriverServer.exe");

    this.driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
    this.driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(4000, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
    driver.get(Constant.URL);

    ExcelUtils.setExcelFile(Constant.Path_TestData + Constant.File_TestData, "Sheet1");

}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Test
public void Activation() throws Exception {

    LoginModel.LoginAdminCredentials(driver);

    driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(4000, TimeUnit.MINUTES);

    String currentURL = driver.getCurrentUrl();

    Assert.assertEquals("expectedURL", currentURL);

}
```

Comment: probably get rid of  `driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(4000, TimeUnit.MINUTES);` in Test

Comment: thanks it works and error is not visible. Even that test is still running too slow. Any ideas how to solve speed issue?

Answer (score 1):

You should get rid of

```
driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(4000, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

in your `@Test` method, since the `driver.manage().timeouts()` value lives till the instance of the driver is alive, be it the default value or a custom value set by the user.

---

Also to reduce the time taken by your execution, you can try and update your `@Before` method by replacing

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(4000, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

with

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(4000, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Comment: Done!! But test again takes 109,322 s. Is there a way to run it for 10 s?

Comment: @evitta15 Are you sure there is no other code related to the above that might take time. Like driver initialization, setting capabilities etc.?

Comment: yes there is, my fault pointing only to test. There is class to read user and pass from excel + constant data :

Comment: yes there is, my fault pointing only to test. But I thought that the problem is because of IE, as same test is running for around 10s using chrome. I checked out IE security settings + using 32 bit driver, as recommended in: https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/5116

Comment: sorry I do not have 15 points to vote to your answer :( But really thank you very much for your help. It helps me a lot :)

Comment: @evitta15 you can always [mark it as an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) though after which you can realize the goodness coming your way as well :)